# Automated Tests on Chromium Embedded Framework 1 with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium-embedded

After conducting an extensive amount of research on trying to find any clues on how to test CEF1-based applications I decided to ask here. Has anyone had any experience or knows about any relevant documents that refer to a Selenium (ChromeDriver) implementation for CEF1-based applications?

I have managed to successfully run CEF3 + ChromeDriver 2.0 tests with Selenium ChromeDriver, but when using a CEF1-based app (or the CEF1 binary release itself) the below error is shown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

I found some information about CEF3 + ChromeDriver 2.0 here: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=549

But nothing about CEF1...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was never implemented for CEF1.